# HTML.ActionLink vs Url.Action in ASP.NET Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there any difference between `HTML.ActionLink` vs `Url.Action` or they are just two ways of doing the same thing?

When should I prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 577, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. `Html.ActionLink` generates an `<a href=".."></a>` tag whereas `Url.Action` returns only an url.

For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }, null)
```

generates:

```
<a href="/somecontroller/someaction/123">link text</a>
```

and `Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" })` generates:

```
/somecontroller/someaction/123
```

There is also [Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) which executes a child controller action.

Comment: hmm....So in case there are hundreds of link on a page, then the HTML.ActionLink might lag since it generates the complete HTML for an anchor, right ??

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay, you should always use html or url helpers when dealing with urls in an asp.net mvc application. Even if you have hundredths of links, use `Html.ActionLink` to generate them. Don't try to do such micro optimizations. You will end up with ugly code in your views.

Comment: dat means I should prefer Html.ActionLink() over Url.Action in all situations when rendering a link is concerned. BTW, then why did Microsoft official tutorial(MVC Music Store) on asp.net website used Url.Action most times whenever a link was needed.

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay, use Html.ActionLink when you need to generate an anchor tag (`<a>`). Use Url.Action when you need to generate only an url (this could also be used in a controller action).

Comment: What's the difference between `Html.Action` and `Html.ActionLink`?

Comment: @Shimmy, you can read about it here: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Comment: I know this is an old post, but something learned from experience. `Url.Action` is much more performat than `Html.ActionLink`. I had a list of 6,000 items that had 2 `Html.ActionLinks`. It took 6,600ms to render the list. Without the `Html.ActionLinks` it took 52ms. Using `Url.Action` it took 270ms. Granted, 6000 items is a large list, but thought I'd add it for future reference.

Answer (score 50):

`Html.ActionLink` generates an `<a href=".."></a>` tag automatically.

`Url.Action` generates only an url.

For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "actionName", "controllerName", new { id = "<id>" }, null)
```

generates:

```
<a href="/controllerName/actionName/<id>">link text</a>
```

and

```
@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { id = "<id>" })
```

generates:

```
/controllerName/actionName/<id>
```

Best plus point which I like is using `Url.Action(...)`

You are creating anchor tag by your own where you can set your own linked text easily even with some other html tag.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { id = "<id>" })">

   <img src="<ImageUrl>" style"width:<somewidth>;height:<someheight> />

   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.<SomeModelField>)
</a>
```

Answer (score 14):

`@HTML.ActionLink` generates a `HTML anchor tag`. While `@Url.Action` generates a `URL` for you. You can easily understand it by;

```
// 1. <a href="/ControllerName/ActionMethod">Item Definition</a>
@HTML.ActionLink("Item Definition", "ActionMethod", "ControllerName")

// 2. /ControllerName/ActionMethod
@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "ControllerName")

// 3. <a href="/ControllerName/ActionMethod">Item Definition</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "ControllerName")"> Item Definition</a>
```

Both of these approaches are different and it totally depends upon your need.

Answer (score 12):

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Company", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by Name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index","Company")'"/>
    </p>
}
```

In the above example you can see that If I specifically need a button to do some action, I have to do it with @Url.Action whereas if I just want a link I will use @Html.ActionLink.
The point is when you have to use some element(HTML) with action url is used.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily present **Html.ActionLink** as a button by using the appropriate CSS style. 
For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save", "ActionMethod", "Controller", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer to original question as to what the difference between HTML.ActionLink vs Url.Action is. Perhaps you should use a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Your answer doesn't entertaining the original query.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code below to create a Button and it worked for me.

```
<input type="button" value="PDF" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Export","tblOrder")'"/>
```

Comment: I think, you have to read the question again. @Pankaj Upadhyay is asking totally different thing.