# Accessing Web Forms from MVC Area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have successfully integrated an MVC area into my web application project.

I would like to create a menu item from one of my MVC Views that links back to the web application Default.aspx.  A "Home" Menu if you will.

Per:  [HTML.ActionLink vs Url.Action in ASP.NET Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor)

I cannot actually use either the HTML.ActionLink nor the URL.Action to do anything but access controllers within the MVC project.

What would be the best way to create this menu heading?

**Where I need the menu item:**
Root>Areas>Folder>Views>Folder>Layout.vbhtml

**To point to:**
Root>Default.aspx

It's quite possible I'm overlooking something quite easy, but as you can tell from my project mess, I'm relatively new to MVC unfortunately.

**Thanks in Advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put

```
<a href="~/Default.aspx">Text...</a>
```

in the view.

Comment: I thought about that.  It does get me there, but I wanted it to look like the other HTML Action Links.  Is that something that I just have to accomplish with CSS?

Comment: I don't understand... when you generate an link using @Html.ActionLink(...) it generates just that anchor element. If you want to define any css class you have to code it with those "new { @class = ... }" parameters. So, yes, anyway you have to define the css.

Comment: You are right of course.  Thank you for your help very much DaniCE.