# How can I use Razor syntax inside a JavaScript file to generate action link on asp.net core framework?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I have a JavaScript file in which I need to generate an action link via Razor syntax.  Here's my code so far.

```
@{
  int ID = @:cardId;
  @:row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = @Url.Action("Details", "Cards", new { Id = ID});
}
```

I want to nest my own text in the link.  ie. `<a>MyText</a>`
However, the Url.Action method is the only method I know of to create a link via Razor and I don't see an overload method that allows me to customize the text of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `Html.ActionLink` here. It has an extra argument that lets you make the link text.

```
@{
  int ID = @:cardId;
  @:row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = @Html.ActionLink("MyText", "Details", "Cards", new { Id = ID }, null)
}
```

Further, I doubt `Url.Action` would've helped you here anyways since it doesn't generate `<a href="some_url_here"></a>`, it only generates `some_url_here`. `Html.ActionLink` generates the entire thing. You can read up on the difference between the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor).