# working with bootstrap scrollspy in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am using Bootstrap ScrollSpy in MVC 5 application.
ScrollSpy works fine with plain html and jquery but I want to implement the same thing in MVC 5.

```
<li><a href="#about" class="hidden-xs">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact" class="hidden-xs">Contact</a></li>
```

the above code works fine, but when I tried to implement the same thing in MVC I somehow get confused.

```
<li> @Html.ActionLink("About", null, null, null, new { @class = "hidden-xs" })</li>
<li> @Html.ActionLink("Contact", null,null, null, new { @class = "hidden-xs" })</li>
```

This is not working as expected as its trying to redirect to specified actionname or I may be doing something wrong.
Suggest something.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap version 3.3.7 ?

Comment: I am using bootstrap v 3.0.0 which is default when you create project template in visual studio.

Comment: Do you only need solution using `@Html.ActionLink` ? because there are several issues to overcome like you have to change routes etc , so shall I provide solution using `@Url.Action` ?

Comment: Sure. You can provide the solution with uri.Action as well.

Comment: If possible aslo try to share the findings why can't we use html.ActionLink here. It would be helpful as I am in learning stage of MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirement for `Bootstrap` `scrollspy` to work, the scrollable elements must match the ID of the links.

Here `<li><a href="#contact" class="hidden-xs">Contact</a></li>` should match div with id `<div id="contact">`

**Using Mvc:**

```
<li> @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Index", "Home", null, null, "contact", null, null)</li>

<li> <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")#contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Check difference between `HTML.ActionLink` vs `Url.Action` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor).

So finally in server side both generates `url` with trailing slash before `hash(#)` as shown below:

```
<a href="/#contact">Contact</a>
```

And thus above link doesn't  match div with id `<div id="contact">` because of `/` before `#`

**Solution Using Mvc:**

Create Custom `UrlHelper`

Create a folder named `Helpers` and add a class named `UrlExtensions` finally add below code:

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{

    public static string HashAnchorLinks(this UrlHelper url, string hashLinkName)
    {

     string hashAnchorLink = string.Format("#{0}", hashLinkName);

     return hashAnchorLink;

    }

}
```

**In View:**

```
@using YourProjectName.Helpers;

<li> <a href="@Url.HashAnchorLinks("about")">About</a></li>
<li> <a href="@Url.HashAnchorLinks("contact")">Contact</a></li>
```

Note:

Best solution would be using plain html as you did before, instead of using server to return the hash link.

References:

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink/275499)

[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor)

[3.](https://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/a-urlhelper-extension-for-creating-absolute-action-paths-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Your not passing the right parameters in into the `ActionLink()`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "Home", "About", new object { }, new { @class = "hidden-xs"})
@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Home", "Contact", new object { }, new { @class = "hidden-xs"})
```

[Here is a explanation of the function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)

Comment: Hi,  I think you have not got the question yet.i am facing issue while working with bootstrap scrollspy in MVC. How to write the actionlink function to get the scrollspy work.