# how can I show different web page address while I open the same web page in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-development-server

I have two web pages. One of them have links to a other web page. The other web page is totally dynamic. I want to open the dynamic web page when i click in the link in the other web page while the address bar should be different each time the dynamic page is opened. I have to do it in ASP.NET.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Is it ASP.NET MVC? If so then you have to display  on the page (View) that have links int  correct format depends on data you have to display on other page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor

Comment: Checkout URL Re-writing