# Calling html with Ajax request from js file OR using Razor methods

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am not sure if the title of my question is ok. I tried to google it but there is not any topic about it.
I am using VS 2017 with MVC project, i have faced two ways to call view (html):

**1st way-Using razor methods which is embedded on html views directly**

`@Html.ActionLink`,`@Url.Action`, etc

**2nd-Using Ajax from a JS file**

```
$.ajax({
               url: "/Controller/Action",
               type: 'GET',
               cache: false,
               success: function (data) {
                   $('#Container').html(data);
               }
       });
```

I would like to know what the difference is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML.ActionLink vs Url.Action in ASP.NET Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor)

Comment: No, it is not the same. I am comparing those ones to Ajax call from  js file

Comment: I suppose you want to compare `Ajax.BeginForm` and Jquery Json post ? If thats case ` Ajax.BeginForm`  and Jquery ajax is same only difference is that `Ajax.BeginForm `will create data from ViewModel and in Jquery ajax you have to provide data by yourself.

Comment: Ajax.BeginForm, Html.actionlink (it creates a link <a>), URL.action (it creates a url string), these ways have something in common, they are embedded in html view and they usually reload the layout. On the other hand Ajax request seems more comfortable because you can customize it. Is it mandatory to use that Razor methods if i work with MVC asp.net project?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink()` creates a `<a>` that makes a redirect. `$.ajax()` makes an ajax calls which stays on the same page (and in you case updates the DOM)